# Solving the heat equation with a source

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

> Solve the heat equation with a source:
>   $$\begin{cases}
> u_t - k u_{xx} = e^{t-x} \ \ &\text{for} \ \ -\infty < x < \infty, t > 0\\
> u(x,0) = 0 \ \ &\text{for} \ \ -\infty < x < \infty\\
> \end{cases}$$
>   Note: the case $k = 1$ should be different then $k\neq 1$

Attempted solution - We will use Duhamel's principle to solve this non-homogeneous problem $$u(x,t) = \int_{0}^{t}w(x,t-T,T)dT$$
Recall that 
\begin{align*}
w(x,t,T) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_n(T)e^{-n^2 x t}\sin(nx)\\
C_n(T) &= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(x,T)\sin(nx)dx \ \ \ n\geq 1\\
u(x,t) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(nx)\int_{0}^{t}C_n(T)e^{-n^2 k(t-T) }dT
\end{align*}
We are given $$f(x,t) = e^{t-x}$$
We first calculate the Fourier coefficients
\begin{align*}
C_n(T) &= \frac{2}{\pi}e^{T-x}\sin(nx)dx\\
&= -\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{T-x}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\cos(nx) \right)dx\\
&= -\frac{2}{n\pi}\left[ e^{T-x}\cos(nx)\Big|_0^\pi \right]\\
&= \frac{2}{n\pi}\left[e^{T} - e^{T - \pi}(-1)^{n+1} \right]\\
&= \frac{2}{n\pi}e^{T}\left[1 - \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{e^{\pi}}\right]
\end{align*} 
We next compute the integral 
\begin{align*}
In(t) &= \int_{0}^{t}C_n(T)e^{-n^2(t-T)}dT\\
&= \int_{0}^{t}\frac{2}{n\pi}e^{T}\left(1 - \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{e^{\pi}} \right)e^{-n^2(t-T)}dT\\
&= \frac{2}{n\pi}e^{-n^2 t}\int_{0}^{t}\left[ e^{T(1 + n^2)} - (-1)^{n+1}e^{T(1+n^2)}e^{-\pi} \right]dT\\
&= \frac{2}{n\pi}e^{-n^2 t}\left[\frac{e^{T}(1 + n^2)}{1 + n^2} - \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{e^{\pi}}\frac{e^{T(1+n^2)}}{1 + n^2}\Big|_0^t \right ]\\
&= \vdots\\
&= \frac{2}{n\pi}\frac{1}{1 + n^2}\left[e^{t}(1 - (-1)^{n+1}) - (1 + e^{-\pi}) \right]
\end{align*}
The final solution is given by $$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}In(t)\sin(nx)$$

I am not sure if this is completely correct, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't checked your solution, but to get something to compare it against: for $k\not = 1$, if you define $v$ via $u = \frac{e^{t-x} - v}{1-k}$ then $v$ satisfy a normal heat equation $v_t = kv_{xx}$ with $v(x,0) = e^{-x}$. From this you can write down the solution directly using the heat kernel.

Comment: @Winther Thank you for that

Comment: Seems that some conditions have been left out. Also a minor error here and there seems to exist. For example: in the "recall that section" $C_{n}(t)$ should not be in the integral and $e^{- n^2 \, x \, t}$ does not seem to fit.

Comment: @Leucippus I made some minor edits I think it is ok now

Comment: Note the equation is posed on the entire real line $-\infty < x < \infty$. You are using methods (namely Fourier series) that work only for bounded intervals.

Comment: @Jeff Does that mean my solution is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, it's not correct. You need to use the fundamental solution (heat kernel) of the heat equation and the corresponding integral representation formula for the solution. I assume you have seen this in your course. You can use Duhamel's method, or the trick by @Winther is a bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the heat equation with a source:
\begin{cases}
u_t - k u_{xx} = e^{t-x} \ \ &\text{for} \ \ -\infty < x < \infty, t > 0\\
u(x,0) = 0 \ \ &\text{for} \ \ -\infty < x < \infty\\
\end{cases}
The solution  is sought in the form
$$u=v(t)e^{-x}.$$
Substitution this in equation yields ode problem
$$v'(t)-kv(t)=e^t,\quad v(0)=0.$$
If $\;k\neq 1$ solution of this problem is
$$v(t)=\frac{e^{k t}-e^t}{k-1}$$
If $\;k=1$
$$v(t)=te^t.$$
Answer:

if $\; k\neq 1$
$$u=\frac{e^{k t}-e^t}{k-1}\,e^{-x}$$
if $\; k=1$
$$u=te^{t-x}$$